# Proving linear dependence

Tags: vector-spaces

$V=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ vectorspace and $f_1,f_2\in V$, so that :
$$\forall c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R} \ (\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \ c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)\geqslant 0 \ \vee \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \ c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)\leqslant 0)$$
Prove that vectors $f_1,f_2$ are linearly dependent.

I understand that in essence, I have to show that this holds: $\exists \lambda \neq 0$, so that $\lambda_1 f_1+\lambda_2 f_2=0 $

Comment: Assume that they're independent. Then there are two points $x$ and $y$ such that $f_1(x)\cdot f_2(y)\neq f_1(y)\cdot f_2(x)$. Use that to make a linear combination that is positive at $x$ and negative at $y$ (or the other way around) thereby violating your condition. Should work, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \left[\begin{matrix} f_1(x) & f_2(x) \\ f_1(y) & f_2(y) \end{matrix}\right] \tag{$\dagger$} $$
is invertible, or there do not.

If there do exist such $x,y$, then in particular the system
$$ \left[\begin{matrix} f_1(x) & f_2(x) \\ f_1(y) & f_2(y) \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{matrix}\right] $$
has a solution, contrary to the hypothesis.

If there do not exist such $x,y$, then the matrix ($\dagger$) always has zero determinant, that is,
$$ f_1(x)f_2(y) - f_2(x)f_1(y) = 0 \qquad\text{for all $x,y$,} \tag{$\ast$} $$
which means $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly dependent.  (Intuitively because this means $f_1/f_2$ is constant, but maybe we're dividing by zero sometimes, so... Formally: If $f_1=0$ we are done; otherwise there exists $x$ such that $f_1(x)\ne 0$, and then $f_1(x)f_2 - f_2(x)f_1$ is the desired nontrivial linear combination.)